# Why does querying an external hive table require write access to the hdfs directory?

Tags: hadoop, hive, file-permissions, partitioning, external-tables

I've hit an interesting permissions problem when setting up an external table to view some Avro files in Hive.

The Avro files are in this directory :

```
drwxr-xr-x   - myserver hdfs          0 2017-01-03 16:29 /server/data/avrofiles/
```

The server can write to this file, but regular users cannot.

As the database admin, I create an external table in Hive referencing this directory:

```
hive> create external table test_table (data string) stored as avro location '/server/data/avrofiles';
```

Now as a regular user I try to query the table:

```
hive> select * from test_table limit 10;
FAILED: HiveException java.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=regular.joe, access=WRITE, inode="/server/data/avrofiles":myserver:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
```

Weird, I'm only trying to read the contents of the file using hive, I'm not trying to write to it.

Oddly, I **don't** get the same problem when I partition the table like this:

As database_admin:

```
hive> create external table test_table_partitioned (data string) partitioned by (value string) stored as avro;
OK
Time taken: 0.104 seconds
hive> alter table test_table_partitioned add if not exists partition (value='myvalue') location '/server/data/avrofiles';
OK
```

As a regular user:

```
hive> select * from test_table_partitioned where value = 'some_value' limit 10;
OK
```

**Can anyone explain this?**

One interesting thing I noticed is that the Location value for the two tables are different and have different permissions:

```
hive> describe formatted test_table;
Location:               hdfs://server.companyname.com:8020/server/data/avrofiles

$ hadoop fs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse/my-database/
drwxr-xr-x   - myserver hdfs          0 2017-01-03 16:29 /server/data/avrofiles/
```

user cannot write

```
hive> describe formatted test_table_partitioned;
Location:               hdfs://server.companyname.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/my-database.db/test_table_partitioned

$ hadoop fs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse/my-database.db/
drwxrwxrwx   - database_admin         hadoop          0 2017-01-04 14:04 /apps/hive/warehouse/my-database.db/test_table_partitioned
```

anyone can do anything :)

Comment: My guess is that temporary files are being created in hdfs under /tmp when u r running your query

Comment: I had the same thought - but I don't think that's it - permissions on /tmp are open:
drwxrwxrwx   - hdfs    hdfs                      0 2016-12-15 13:52 /tmp

and the error was specifically about write access to /server/data/avrofiles